# Performing an action after a RowSort operation

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` and a `TableRowSorter` which I'd like to perform an operation *after* a sort is finished. I've been browsing the net, and so far I haven't had much luck.

Initially I thought just a `RowSorterListener` would do the trick, but unfortunately it doesn't perform the operation after the sort is finished.

Adding a `MouseListener` to the `JTable` header could work, but the solution isn't terribly elegant.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a bunch!

---

**Edit** (from comment):  The following is added in a method inside a custom `TableModel` class which extends `AbstractTableModel`. This method is invoked whenever the `JTable` is set/specified in the custom `TableModel` class.

```
sorter.addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {
    @Override public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent rowsorterevent) {
        rebuildMItems(); // The method which executes
    }
});
```

Comment: `RowSorterListener` should work.  can you show how you are adding the RowSorterListener and the implementation of your `sorterChanged` method?

Comment: Akf, thanks for your help.

The following is added in a method inside a custom `TableModel` class which extends `AbstractTableModel`. This method is invoked whenever the `JTable` is set/specified in the custom `TableModel` class.

<pre>
sorter.addRowSorterListener(new RowSorterListener() {
  @Override
  public void sorterChanged(RowSorterEvent rowsorterevent) {
    rebuildMItems(); // The method which executes
  }
});
</pre>

Nothing too exciting though :P

Comment: Oops, looks like the formatting went awry there. Could you tell I'm new to Stack Overflow? :)

Comment: You can't format anything in comments. Could you add it to the question instead please?

Comment: are you suggesting that rebuildMItems() does in fact get called, but it is called too early?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. I see you have a custom `RowSorter`. Couldn't you simply add a call to your operation at the end of the `sort()` method?

   In other words, can you add this:

   ```
   @Override
   public void sort() {
       super.sort();
       doSomethingAfterSortingIsDone();
   }
   ```

   to your sorter?
2. Your current method (doing it in a `RowSorterListener`) performs the operation twice: once for `SORT_ORDER_CHANGED` and once for `SORTED`. Can you check the event's [type](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/RowSorterEvent.html#getType()) and only perform the operation at the correct time?